# What is the spurious block in the display of GWT nested TabLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt

In a GWTP app I have a TabLayoutPanel nested within another TabLayoutPanel. I'm using UiBinder for each Presenter/View.

I've not included the UiBinder lines here (apologies) but I'm struggling to see why nesting TabLayoutPanel adds an extra orange thin unlabeled block of color (see image below) between the two tab rows. The top-level tabs that have a VerticalPanel rather than nested TabLayoutPanel lack the extra unlabeled orange block.

Have you come across this display before?

My MainView.ui.xml looks like this:

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="2" barUnit="EM">
<g:tab>
    <g:header>Invite</g:header>
    <g:VerticalPanel/>
</g:tab>

<g:tab>
    <g:header>News</g:header>
    <g:VerticalPanel/>
</g:tab>

<g:tab>
    <g:header>Teams</g:header>
    <g:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="2" barUnit="EM"/>
</g:tab>

</g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

For that third tab, is it correct to nest another TabLayoutPanel after the <g:header>?

My nested TabLayoutPanel is straightforwardly defined with each tab of this format:

```
<g:tab>
    <g:header>All Teams</g:header>
    <g:VerticalPanel/>
</g:tab>
```

Google Developer Tools reveals that another DIV with class="gwt-TabLayoutPabelTab get-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected" is inserted between this top-level TabLayoutPanel and the nested TabLayoutPanel. This extra tab is nested within a DIV with class "gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs".

These extra DIVs display an extra block between the two rows of tabs.

[image]

Comment: for these kind of issues. The best thing is to check with Chrome Dev Tools and see what exactly is shown here. Without UiBinder code it's hard to tell what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spurious block is avoided when a VerticalPanel is used and the required nested TabLayoutPanel is placed within that Vertical Panel.

In MainView.ui.xml instead of:

```
<g:tab>
    <g:header>Teams</g:header>
    <g:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="2" barUnit="EM"/>
</g:tab>
```

use this:

```
<g:tab>
    <g:header>Teams</g:header>
    <g:VerticalPanel/>
</g:tab>
```

and then in the UiBinder file for Teams:

```
<g:VerticalPanel>
   <g:TabLayoutPanel ...>
       <g:tab>
           ...
```

By adding the "extra" VerticalPanel one prevents GWT from adding an extra "ghost" TabLayoutPanel.